# Multiple lines in a node of a treeview?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, f#, treeview

Can a node in a treeview contain multiple lines of text? Is it possible to coerce it to do so if no direct way is possible (which seems likely)?

Programming in F#, .Net 4.0, winforms.

Comment: I'm not familiar with your environment, but tried to programatically assign `"some text\nmore text"` to node text property?

Comment: Or you mean text wrapping for a fixed width?

Comment: @helios: yes I have tried inserting a newline. Didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

I have never needed to have text on multiple lines on a node, but here is another suggestion.

Consider using a fixed number of char (ie. 100) and then the whole text as a title?

So,

```
-->
  |
   --> This is my very long..
```

Then when hovering over the node

```
This is my very long text message.
That you can only see when hovering over the node. :)
```

Comment: I am considering alternatives such as yours, or expanding the whole text on a different control if needed. But I was hoping if a direct solution to my problem exists.

Comment: Another option could be to perhaps have a multi line textbox (with its settings to look like a label) and when you click on any node, it will display the full text within that textbox.

I can't think of anything other viable solution at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

There's the posibility to override the way nodes are drawn (or just its text).

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treeview.drawnode.aspx

Anyway it seems pretty complicated just to get multiline support...

Comment: I am already using that to override drawing the text. Can you describe a way to use that for multiple lines?

Comment: Not really :( It seems that TreeView handles all the size decision. I don't really know too much about it...

Answer (score 0):

Try this
 TreeNode tnode_child_item = new TreeNode();
 tnode_child_item.Text = "  first line < br/> second line  ";

output will be like 
+  first line
     second line

Comment: Web Forms TreeView is a completely different control. It has the System.Web.UI.WebControls.TreeView.NodeWrap property, though.